# Do integer powers distribute over a multiplication of disjoint cycles?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

Is it true that $(c_1c_2*...*c_k)^m = c_1^mc_2^m*...*c_k^m$ if every $c_i$ is a cycle and every pair $(c_i,c_k)$ is disjoint without any other condition?

I have seen some proofs that to my understanding use this fact but I cannot find it expicitly somewhere written and that's usually a sign that does not hold. But I tried to prove it for cycles of length 2 and seems like it works. I could not find it though, if it is a duplicate refer me to the corresponding question but please let it be something that verifies my statement and not some close to it because I am new to the field of abstract algebra.

Comment: Yes. Disjoint cycles commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You don't even need to know that they are cycles, only that they commute (for example, their supports are disjoint).

In general, if $G$ is an arbitrary (semi)group and $c_1,\ldots,c_k\in G$ commute, then straightforward induction shows that $(c_1c_2\cdots c_k)^n=c_1^nc_2^n\cdots c_k^n$.